# wild card search in logstash.conf for files

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm new to **ELK**, tried loading a log file into *`elastic search`* which worked successfully.
Now planning to load all the log files from a specific folder into *`elastic search`*
Below is the `input`  part in the configuration file. I have a regex expression there to load files such as `test2312312.log`, `test35353.log` and `test743432.log`. The expression should ignores files like `testserver.log`, `testprocess.log`

The below regex used to work in `Python` but it is not working here in `GROK`. Can someone help me out?

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/Users/myself/Downloads/ELK/test(?=[0-9]).log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NULL"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path in file doesn't support regex. It only supports wildcard.

You can use exclude property which accepts an array to [exclude](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-exclude) certain files

> Exclusions (matched against the filename, not full path). Filename
>   patterns are valid here, too. For example, if you have